# self-executing anonymous functions and call it again

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do something like this:

```
var build= (function(){
  //my function body     
})();

function test(){
   //somthing then call build
   build() //i want to call build function again in my code
}
```

How can I do this?
I tried this in angular:

```
var buildRoot = (() => {

                $SubNode.get({
                    TypeID: vendorAdminService.NodeType.Category
                }, function(data: vendorAdminService.IGetNodeParameters) {
                    $scope.ProductTree = data.TreeNodeModelItem;
                    $scope.AjaxLoading = false;

                }, function(err) {
                    // alert(err)
                })
        })();
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
                $Category.Remove(node.ID)
                buildRoot
            }, function() {

            });
```

but it does not work. 
Anybody can guide me??

Comment: your IIFE needs to return a function, for later calling. but then there is no need for an anonymous function.

Comment: `var build = (function() {
  var func = function() {
    alert();
  };
  func();
  return func;
})();

function test() {
  build();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a function in your IIFE.
If you IIF is not trivial and has many functionalities you could also consider using [Reveal Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

```js
var build = (function() {
  var f = function() {
    console.log('hello');
  };
  f();
  return f;
})();

function test() {
  build();
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a named function.

Your IIFE needs to return a function, for later calling. But then is no need for an anonymous function.

```
function build() {
     //my function body
}
```

or

```
var build = function () {
         //my function body
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var build = (function() {

    var init = function() {
        // magic code
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }

}());

function test() {
    build.init()
}

test();
```

You include all your functionalities inside your build object, and you'll be able to call them as soon as you return them from inside that object. This effectively is called the *revealing module pattern*

For more information, [read this](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are missing semi-colons ";"

```
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
            $Category.Remove(node.ID);
            buildRoot();
        }, function() {

        });
```

Comment: in JavaScript semi-colons is optional